# Merge Two Binary Tree- LeetCode

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, tree

I solved this problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-binary-trees/#/description)

> Given two binary trees and imagine that when you put one of them to
>   cover the other, some nodes of the two trees are overlapped while the
>   others are not.
>
> You need to merge them into a new binary tree. The merge rule is that
>   if two nodes overlap, then sum node values up as the new value of the
>   merged node. Otherwise, the NOT null node will be used as the node of
>   new tree.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
> Input: 
>   Tree 1                     Tree 2                  
>           1                         2                             
>          / \                       / \                            
>         3   2                     1   3                        
>        /                           \   \                      
>       5                             4   7                  
> Output: 
> Merged tree:
>        3
>       / \
>      4   5
>     / \   \ 
>    5   4   7
> ```
>
> Note: The merging process must start from the root nodes of both trees.

The code that I had written is.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public TreeNode left;
 *     public TreeNode right;
 *     public TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public enum Direction
    {
        Left, Right, None
    }
    public TreeNode doMerge(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2, Direction direction, TreeNode t3)
        {
            if(t1 == null && t2 == null)
            {
                return t3;
            }
            if(t1 == null || t2 == null)
            {
                TreeNode notNullTree = t1 == null ? t2 : t1;
                switch(direction)
                {
                    case Direction.None:
                        return notNullTree;
                    case Direction.Left:
                        t3.left = notNullTree;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Right:
                        t3.right = notNullTree;
                        break;
                }
                return t3;
            }
            var newNode = new TreeNode(t1.val + t2.val);
            switch (direction)
            {

                case Direction.None:
                    t3 = newNode;
                    break;
                case Direction.Left:
                    t3.left = newNode;
                    t3 = t3.left;
                    break;
                case Direction.Right:
                    t3.right = newNode;
                    t3 = t3.right;
                    break;
            }
            doMerge(t1.left, t2.left, Direction.Left, t3);
            doMerge(t1.right, t2.right, Direction.Right, t3);
            return t3;
        }
        public TreeNode MergeTrees(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2)
        {
            return doMerge(t1, t2, Direction.None, null);
        }
}
```

The code has a lot of conditionals which could be refactored. Any suggestion on making the code a bit cleaner and concise would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem!

Firstly, you have correctly identified the 3 possible states:

- `both tree1 and tree2 are null`
- `tree1 or tree2 is null`
- `both tree1 and tree2 are not null`

That being said, I would recommend a couple of things:

1. Break up the problem into 4 possible states (i.e., don't handle the case when `tree1 or tree2 is null` in one conditional statement.
2. if passing in the merged tree `tree3` to `doMerge` in order to modify it in the method, you should utilize C#'s [out](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out) parameter.
3. Why do you need the `Direction` enum? It seems to make the code harder to understand.

Here is my implementation of `doMerge`:

```
public TreeNode MergeTrees(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) 
{
    if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return null;
    if (t1 != null && t2 == null) return t1;
    if (t1 == null && t2 != null) return t2;
    TreeNode merged = new TreeNode(t1.val + t2.val);
    merged.left = MergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left);
    merged.right = MergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right);
    return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterative what you can do is make the recursive version as @ljeabmreson.

I successfully submitted this code on leetcode

```
public class Solution {
    public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
        return func(t1,t2);

    }

    public TreeNode func(TreeNode n1,TreeNode n2)
    {
        if(n1 == null && n2 == null)
            return null;

        else if(n1 != null && n2 != null)
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode(n1.val + n2.val);
            n.left = func(n1.left,n2.left);
            n.right = func(n1.right,n2.right);
            return n;
        }
        else if(n1 != null && n2 == null)
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode(n1.val);
            n.left = func(n1.left,null);
            n.right = func(n1.right,null);
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode(n2.val);
            n.left = func(null,n2.left);
            n.right = func(null,n2.right);
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

But actually @ljeabmreson's version is a bit better as if only one of them is null, he is simply returning the other node and hence saving on time and space.

Comment: My version is not iterative. Its recursive as well.

Comment: i told that only. "make the recursive version as @ljeabmreson.". and i even mentioned that your code is a bit better than mine as well as it saves on space and time. :)